# BS4 Cards won't fit in parent div

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I have 2 cards above each other inside a parent-div. This parent-div's height is dynamic. Now the problem I have is that the 2 cards don't fit inside of the parent-div. I suspect that the issue here is the table inside of the lower card, that is probably not responsive and not triggering it's overflow right. So what I want to achieve is these 2 cards nicely fitting in the parent-div where only the table adjusts (triggers overflow) to make them fit.

I reproduced my issue here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-8h1b14?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: I think it better setting parent div to max height and overflow y to auto ....

Comment: Would be a solution but not really for my actual project since I don't want the top card to be out of sight when I scroll down to check out the table contents

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a fixed height to the card and set height to 100% on the card-content and the table container.
Then you can set overflow-y:scroll on the table-container like so :

```
.fixed-height {
  height: 400px;
}
.card-body {
  background-color: #303030;
  color: #fffcf2;
  height: 100%;
}

.overflow-scroll {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

See the result on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-ppthec?file=app/app.component.css).

Comment: You think it's possible to achieve this result without the fixed-height class?